# does firebase web api version 2.x support the return of a promise for set and update when writing realtime data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The documentation in the following link states,

"To know when your data is committed to the Firebase Realtime Database server, you can use a Promise. Both set() and update() can return a Promise you can use to know when the write is committed to the database."

It is a safe assumption that this is in reference to firebase web api 3.x ?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

Promises were introduced in version 2.4 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK. They are also supported in version 3.x of the SDK.

See this [announcement blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html) and the [release notes](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html).